# Outlook rule for desktop-only notification

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'd like to set a rule where matches trigger a desktop notification with no mobile notification. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

> > matches trigger a desktop notification with no mobile notification

Do you mean that you only want to get notification on the desktop client and not want to get notification on your mobile phone when receiving emails?

I did some research and it seems that Outlook rule will not affect the notification on your mobile phone. To disable mobile notification, please check these articles below:

[How can I turn on/off push notifications & sounds?](https://www.osupportweb.com/a/outlook-mobile/?s=notifications-sounds&f=how-can-i-turn-on-off-push-notifications-sounds)

[Optimize the Outlook mobile app for your phone or tablet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/optimize-the-outlook-mobile-app-for-your-ios-or-android-phone-de075b19-b73c-4d8a-841b-459982c7e890)

Comment: Not exactly. For example. If I get an email from my boss, I want to have a desktop notification and a mobile notification. If I get an email from Jira, I only want to get a desktop notification.

Comment: As I know, we can set in desktop client to only receive email notifications from specific users, but there seems to be no information about setting up this on the mobile phone.  What about the “See conversations and notifications from your favorite contacts” mentioned in the articles before?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't address my specific issue.